# How to raise a matrix to a power in C programming language

Tags: c

I'm trying to raise a matrix to a power for an assignment in my college but I'm having problems. I'm using this code to do that but its not working and I can't understand why. Can someone help?

```
void RaiseThem(float x[][3], float y[][3], int b){ 
    int i,j,w,k;
    for( i = 0 ; i < 2 ; ++ i )
          for( j = 0 ; j < 2 ; ++ j ) 
           y[i][j] = ( i == j ) ;


    float temp[3][3];

    for(w=0;w<b;w++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                temp[i][j]=0;
                for(k=0;k<2;k++)
                {
                    temp[i][j]+=y[i][k]*x[k][j];
                }
            }
        }

        for(i=0;i<2;i++){
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                y[i][j]=temp[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? You need to describe that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The bounds of your loops are too small.

Your matrix is (presumably) 3x3, so the indexes are 0-2.  You're checking `i < 2` and `j < 2`, so `i` and `j` cannot be 2.

You need to change your tests to `i < 3` and `j < 3`.